# Create a real folder based on a playlist in Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-media-player

Given a playlist in Windows Media Player 12, is there a plugin I can use that can copy those files to a folder with the location and name I specify?

Comment: +1 Interesting question. I, too, would like to know that :-)

Comment: More like that question is a duplicate of this one. This was asked 5 months earlier.